# need to identify "g7" chip or IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microchip

I have a corsair power supply.The computer will only turn on if I switch the power supply off and back on. Then I press the PC power button. If I don't do this and I shut down the PC and turn it on without switching off and on the power supply hardly anything turns on the computer. Now I found the problem However, I cannot Identify the IC or the chip. I'm new  at identifying these sort of things. Which is why I'm asking if anyone has seen this chip before. The Chip or IC says G7 or something as a logo and the code next to that is I think 60339 or 60335. I'm still unsure. I'm trying to buy a new one that I may repair this power supply. I have a picture of the IC if anyone is able to identify it.

[image: IC or chip?]

**update 8-100-2017 10:16 AM :**
Cleaned up the IC a bit it doesn't seem to be the problem. The last picture made it look terribly damaged. So my apologies on that last picture. Not so sure this is the problem but I got the clear picture now. 
[image: Cleaned Up]

**update 2017 Aug 10 :**
I'm scraping the power supply and getting another one.

Comment: The logo is ST, for ST Microelectronics. It's extremely difficult to make out what the rest of it is. Do you have a better resolution picture?

Comment: thats how the chip looks like the chip is all messed up. i wish i could better view.

Comment: If you shine a light on it from an angle and take a picture from a perpendicular angle, it may highlight any laser etching. Also, your camera has focused on the PCB itself rather than on the top of the chip (the traces are very clear, but the edges on the chip are extremely undefined).

Comment: What's the PSU model?

Comment: Could you wash it up with some solvent before taking the picture? Also, dual comparators as LM393 are frequently used in PSUs...

Comment: @KingDuken The PSU model is Corsair Rm1000

Comment: @AliChen Cleaned up it up nicely now.

Comment: @LosFrijoles The numbers seem pretty clear now. However, not sure this is the problem anymore. I guess I should just scrap this PSU. Since I'm not sure what the problem exact problem is. Im still contemplating whether or not I should just get a new one.

Comment: It is a very good idea to scrap this PSU. The problem can be anywhere, in deterioration of snubber circuits (leading to excessive ringing or switch time), or in rectifier fatigue, or in isolation break-down in high-voltage transfoemer, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part is a [LM393](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm393.pdf). SO8 package, made by ST Microelectronics.

This part is not particularly likely to fail during use, and I wouldn't expect its failure to cause the symptoms you're describing.